# ubuntu can't listen 0.0.0.0

Tags: linux, ubuntu, webserver

I'm trying to run program in my IP address in port:1433 that to run from web but only program running in my IP.
when I use `$netstat -na | grep LISTEN`  command return this:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1433            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7071            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10050           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:6942          :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::10050                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:63342         :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9614          :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

Comment: And what is the actual problem you have? What about that `netstat` output are you wondering about? Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then please [edit] your question to improve it (like for example actually asking a question).

Comment: What kind of web server is this? Do you have any config files for us to go on? Have you tried localhost:1433 in your browser instead of your ip address? Please when you are asking a question tell us what you are trying to do, what you have tried to do, and state the question clearly. Also you can give [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com) a try when asking linux/unix related questions or if you can't get help here. Good luck to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0.0.0.0 mean the system is listening on all IP addresses on the system -- it's a shortcut so netstat doesn't need to list out, for example, the five IP's you've got configured on a box. If you bind a service to a specific IP, it'll show up specifically (including stuff bound to localhost, where you see 127.0.0.1).